# Problems with file system

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition, linux-kernel, ext4

I created a partition with EXT4 file system and when I'm writing in this partition frequently the Kernel return the following error:

```
Jan 01 01:17:54 infobuffer360 kernel:  r7:c0561280
Jan 01 01:17:54 infobuffer360 kernel: [<c00120b8>] (die+0x0/0x380) from [<c001245c>] (arm_notify_die+0x24/0x5c)
Jan 01 01:17:54 infobuffer360 kernel: [<c0012438>] (arm_notify_die+0x0/0x5c) from [<c000833c>] (do_undefinstr+0x1a8/0x1d4)
Jan 01 01:17:54 infobuffer360 kernel: [<c0008194>] (do_undefinstr+0x0/0x1d4) from [<c000e00c>] (__und_svc_finish+0x0/0x34)
Jan 01 01:17:54 infobuffer360 kernel: Exception stack(0xd84cbaf8 to 0xd84cbb40)
Jan 01 01:17:54 infobuffer360 kernel: bae0:                                                       d9036884 fffffffc
Jan 01 01:17:54 infobuffer360 kernel: bb00: 00000001 00000000 d84ca000 d90026c0 d9036848 c05aa908 00001350 d91f2db0
Jan 01 01:17:54 infobuffer360 kernel: bb20: 00000007 d84cbb5c 00000000 d84cbb40 c016818c c016827c 60000013 ffffffff
Jan 01 01:17:54 infobuffer360 kernel:  r9:c000e00c r8:00001350 r7:d84cbb2c r6:ffffffff r5:60000013
                                      r4:c0168280
Jan 01 01:17:54 infobuffer360 kernel: [<c01680e4>] (jbd2_journal_add_journal_head+0x0/0x1c4) from [<c015f8dc>] (jbd2_journal_get_write_access+0x18/0x40)
Jan 01 01:17:55 infobuffer360 kernel:  r7:c03a1b08 r6:d90026c0 r5:d90343a0 r4:00000000
Jan 01 01:17:55 infobuffer360 kernel: [<c015f8c4>] (jbd2_journal_get_write_access+0x0/0x40) from [<c0146b84>] (__ext4_journal_get_write_access+0x38/0x78)
Jan 01 01:17:55 infobuffer360 kernel:  r5:d90343a0 r4:00000000
Jan 01 01:17:55 infobuffer360 kernel: [<c0146b4c>] (__ext4_journal_get_write_access+0x0/0x78) from [<c012b3c8>] (ext4_reserve_inode_write+0x6c/0x9c)
Jan 01 01:17:55 infobuffer360 kernel:  r8:c08845e0 r7:d90343a0 r6:d84cbbd4 r5:d91f2db0 r4:00000000
Jan 01 01:17:55 infobuffer360 kernel: [<c012b35c>] (ext4_reserve_inode_write+0x0/0x9c) from [<c012b420>] (ext4_mark_inode_dirty+0x28/0x188)
Jan 01 01:17:55 infobuffer360 kernel:  r7:d9695800 r6:d90343a0 r5:d91f2db0 r4:d91f2db0
Jan 01 01:17:55 infobuffer360 kernel: [<c012b3f8>] (ext4_mark_inode_dirty+0x0/0x188) from [<c012e3bc>] (ext4_dirty_inode+0x38/0x58)
Jan 01 01:17:55 infobuffer360 kernel:  r8:c08845e0 r7:00000000 r6:00071da9 r5:d90343a0 r4:d91f2db0
Jan 01 01:17:55 infobuffer360 kernel: [<c012e384>] (ext4_dirty_inode+0x0/0x58) from [<c00d9814>] (__mark_inode_dirty+0x34/0x268)
Jan 01 01:17:55 infobuffer360 kernel:  r5:d91f2db0 r4:00000007
Jan 01 01:17:55 infobuffer360 kernel: [<c00d97e0>] (__mark_inode_dirty+0x0/0x268) from [<c00e15bc>] (generic_write_end+0xbc/0xec)
Jan 01 01:17:55 infobuffer360 kernel:  r8:c08845e0 r7:00000000 r6:00071da9 r5:00000000 r4:00071da9
                                      r3:c08845e0
Jan 01 01:17:55 infobuffer360 kernel: [<c00e1500>] (generic_write_end+0x0/0xec) from [<c012d638>] (ext4_da_write_end+0x90/0x224)
Jan 01 01:17:55 infobuffer360 kernel: [<c012d5a8>] (ext4_da_write_end+0x0/0x224) from [<c007ff5c>] (generic_file_buffered_write+0x104/0x294)
Jan 01 01:17:55 infobuffer360 kernel: [<c007fe58>] (generic_file_buffered_write+0x0/0x294) from [<c0081ae8>] (__generic_file_aio_write+0x1d8/0x4bc)
Jan 01 01:17:55 infobuffer360 kernel: [<c0081910>] (__generic_file_aio_write+0x0/0x4bc) from [<c0081e28>] (generic_file_aio_write+0x5c/0xc0)
Jan 01 01:17:55 infobuffer360 kernel: [<c0081dcc>] (generic_file_aio_write+0x0/0xc0) from [<c0123b88>] (ext4_file_write+0xb8/0x4d4)
Jan 01 01:17:55 infobuffer360 kernel: [<c0123ad0>] (ext4_file_write+0x0/0x4d4) from [<c00b2120>] (do_sync_write+0x7c/0xa4)
Jan 01 01:17:55 infobuffer360 kernel: [<c00b20a4>] (do_sync_write+0x0/0xa4) from [<c00b28dc>] (vfs_write+0xbc/0x19c)
Jan 01 01:17:55 infobuffer360 kernel:  r9:00000007 r8:00000001 r7:00000007 r6:d84cbf78 r5:a99dc708
                                      r4:d97493e0
Jan 01 01:17:55 infobuffer360 kernel: [<c00b2820>] (vfs_write+0x0/0x19c) from [<c00b2ed8>] (SyS_write+0x44/0x80)
Jan 01 01:17:55 infobuffer360 kernel:  r9:00000007 r8:00000001 r7:a99dc708 r6:d97493e0 r5:00000000
                                      r4:00000000
Jan 01 01:17:55 infobuffer360 kernel: [<c00b2e94>] (SyS_write+0x0/0x80) from [<c000e3a0>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30)
Jan 01 01:17:55 infobuffer360 kernel:  r9:d84ca000 r8:c000e548 r7:00000004 r6:a99dc708 r5:00000007
                                      r4:b45fae80
```

Someone known how can I fix it and why is it happening?

When I type journalctl command it return the following error:

```
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: Kernel BUG at c016827c [verbose debug info unavailable]
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: Internal error: Oops - BUG: 0 [#1] PREEMPT ARM
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: Modules linked in: spi_bcm2708 i2c_bcm2708 ipv6
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 38 Comm: jbd2/mmcblk0p2- Not tainted 3.10.27-quick #1
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: task: d958b180 ti: d95f2000 task.ti: d95f2000
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: PC is at jbd2_journal_add_journal_head+0x198/0x1c4
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: LR is at jbd2_journal_add_journal_head+0xa8/0x1c4
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: pc : [<c016827c>]    lr : [<c016818c>]    psr: 60000113
                                      sp : d95f3d40  ip : 00000000  fp : d95f3d5c
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: r10: ffffffff  r9 : d9037ee4  r8 : d95f3da0
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: r7 : c05aa908  r6 : d9038548  r5 : d9002ba0  r4 : d95f2000
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: r3 : 00000000  r2 : 00000001  r1 : fffffffc  r0 : d9038584
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: Flags: nZCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment kernel
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: Control: 00c5387d  Table: 1813c008  DAC: 00000017
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: Process jbd2/mmcblk0p2- (pid: 38, stack limit = 0xd95f21b0)
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: Stack: (0xd95f3d40 to 0xd95f4000)
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: 3d40: d9002ba0 d957d400 d957d400 d95f3eb4 d95f3d84 d95f3d60 c0168340 c01680f0
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: 3d60: 00000400 c001b5d4 00022eba 00000000 00001461 00000000 d95f3e2c d95f3d88
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: 3d80: c0160d08 c01682b4 c002786c c0072208 00000000 c0574858 d95f3dc4 d95f3da8
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: 3da0: c000f2b4 c00277f0 c0162108 c00e177c 60000113 f200b200 d95f3dd4 d95f3dc8
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: 3dc0: d95f3e14 d95f3dd0 c015f1d0 c015e4c0 c000def4 c000818c d91b7d48 00000000
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: 3de0: 00000001 00000001 00000000 11490c80 c05aa908 d9038548 00001461 11490c80
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: 3e00: d95f3e2c 00000000 00000000 d9037ee0 d95f2030 d91b78c8 d95f3e30 00000000
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: 3e20: d95f3f14 d95f3e30 c01621d8 c0160cb0 00022eb9 00000000 ffffffff 00000000
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: 3e40: d95f3e74 d6131c2c bec23158 000004be 00000000 00000002 00000000 00000000
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: 3e60: 00000000 000001f4 00000000 00000000 000780d1 d9037ee0 d95f2030 00000008
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: 3e80: d9584600 000003d4 d95f3ec8 d9037f14 00000003 00000000 ffffffff d957d400
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: 3ea0: d6131c2c d95f2000 bec23158 000004be d9038a08 00000000 00000eb2 00009f83
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: 3ec0: 00022eb9 00000000 91827364 d95f3ecc d95f3ecc d95f3ed4 d95f3ed4 d957d600
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: 3ee0: d95f3f14 d95f3ef0 c002d7a0 d957d400 d957d440 d95f2018 d957d600 d95f2018
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: 3f00: c05a7404 d95f2000 d95f3f64 d95f3f18 c0165d78 c0160f10 d95f3f44 d957d450
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: 3f20: c0395c00 00000000 d958b180 c0040f40 d95f3f30 d95f3f30 c0165c98 d9439b4c
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: 3f40: 00000000 d957d400 c0165c98 00000000 00000000 00000000 d95f3fac d95f3f68
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: 3f60: c0040624 c0165ca4 c0c0c0c0 00000000 c0c0c0c0 d957d400 00000000 d95f3f7c
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: 3f80: d95f3f7c 00000000 d95f3f88 d95f3f88 d9439b4c c0040578 00000000 00000000
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: 3fa0: 00000000 d95f3fb0 c000e438 c0040584 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: 3fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: 3fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000 c0c0c0c0 c0c0c0c0
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: Backtrace:
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: [<c01680e4>] (jbd2_journal_add_journal_head+0x0/0x1c4) from [<c0168340>] (jbd2_journal_get_descriptor_buffer+0x98/0xc0)
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel:  r7:d95f3eb4 r6:d957d400 r5:d957d400 r4:d9002ba0
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: [<c01682a8>] (jbd2_journal_get_descriptor_buffer+0x0/0xc0) from [<c0160d08>] (journal_submit_commit_record.isra.25+0x64/0x2--More-60)
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel:  r5:00000000 r4:00001461
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: [<c0160ca4>] (journal_submit_commit_record.isra.25+0x0/0x260) from [<c01621d8>] (jbd2_journal_commit_transaction+0x12d4/0x1--More-a08)
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: [<c0160f04>] (jbd2_journal_commit_transaction+0x0/0x1a08) from [<c0165d78>] (kjournald2+0xe0/0x2fc)
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: [<c0165c98>] (kjournald2+0x0/0x2fc) from [<c0040624>] (kthread+0xac/0xb8)
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: [<c0040578>] (kthread+0x0/0xb8) from [<c000e438>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x3c)
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel:  r7:00000000 r6:00000000 r5:c0040578 r4:d9439b4c
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: Code: 0a000002 e5933004 e3530000 1affffab (e7f001f2)
Jan 01 01:26:57 infobuffer360 kernel: ---[ end trace d7e3575ed2ea4082 ]---
```

Comment: Feels like a disk write error. Does your disk support SMART? I'd recommend checking it for errors (e.g. `smartctl -t long /dev/sda` and then, later, `smartctl -a /dev/sda`)

Comment: it doesn't have support =(, I printed the journal log, is it possible to find the problem from it?

Comment: Have you tried `e2fsck -f` on the partition (without it mounted, of course)?

Comment: Also, that looks like you've hit a kernel bug, a hardware issue, or maybe compiled your kernel with a feature your CPU doesn't support (picked slightly the wrong CPU—though I have no idea if that would even boot)